# в чем отличие виртуальной функции от шаблонной функции?

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, чем отличается виртуальная функция от шаблонной функции?

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "чем отличается ориентированный граф от графа Монте-Кристо"....

Comment: Сначала изучите организацию работы шаблонной функции. Затем как работает виртуальная. Отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко говоря - эти функции отличаются почти всем. :-)

Это две разные концепции.

Виртуальные функции обеспечивают полиморфизм классам. (Концепция, поддерживаемая языком С++ при помощи небольшого, скрытого от пользователя оверхеда по памяти и быстродействию).

Шаблонные функции позволяют сделать типы параметрами функций. (Концепция, поддерживаемая языком С++ без помощи оверхеда по памяти и быстродействию).